# Где найти пример реализации mvp?

Tags: java, android, swing, mvp, консоль

Начал применять в своей практике паттерн проектирования MVP. Как я понимаю этот паттерн помогает переносить ядро приложения на разные платформы.
Вот и хотелось бы увидеть пример такого приложения, которое перенесено на несколько платформ. Хотелось бы увидеть пример для `cli` и что-то из Android/Swing Если есть такая возможность показать поэтапную разработку.

Comment: Паттерн помогает отделить мух от котлет, а не пренос на разные платформы

Comment: MVP - Model View Presenter - паттерн организации взаимодействия между данными и их отображением на экране. Этот паттерн (как и его родственники MVC, MVVM и др.) может использоваться на совершенно разных платформах, но ни о каком переносе ядра речи не идет и идти не может, это просто принцип организации обмена данных, а не какая то технология. Для каждой платформы он реализуется по принципам этой конкретной платформы, а не универсального ядра. В общем нет такого приложения Android/Swing и не появится.

Comment: @pavlofff, @Stranger in the Q  
Я поясню, что я имел ввиду.  
Этот паттерн не переносит приложение на разные платформы, но помогает это сделать. Для примера: есть ядро, которое проверяет `login/pass` написанное как `model` для cli. Все приложение для проверки `login/pass` написано под `mvp`.
Как я могу перенести это приложение на android, с минимальной работой. Мне переписать `View+Presenter` или только `View`?

Comment: @Jorik вам нужно всю логику перенести в Presenter

Comment: @Jorik, если хотите пример, то есть курс где подробно об этом рассказывают, а также применяют библиотеку Moxy для этого паттерна.
Курс находится на coursera.org. Быстрый старт в Android разработку. 3 курс в специализации. Но доступ к нему открыт только на неделю, так что лучше видео скачайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько статей на эту тему по части реализации: 
MVP 
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/505-mvp-v-android-dlja-samihkh-malenjhkikh
MVVM MMVC MVP и т.д.
https://habr.com/ru/post/344184/
Надесь вам поможет. Есть еще множество разных статей про это, но эти паттерны, как читал, чаще всего используются не как жесткие решения, а как примерная структура приложения, которую желательно реализовать в зависимости от его целей.

UPD: 
https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html
MVP ENG SWING 
https://riptutorial.com/swing/example/14137/simple-mvp-example